# Laravel проблемы с компиляцией css и js

Tags: javascript, css, laravel

Вроде после команды npm run dev, vite должен собрать css и js и поместить в build.
Вместо этот стартует сервер. Следую обучающему видео Bootstrap в laravel, канала Laravel Creative.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `npm run dev` запускает development сервер [Running Vite](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/vite#running-vite)

Comment: Да, но какая команда тогда отвечает за сборку ресурсов для билда?

Comment: `npm run build`, вроде логично, что если `dev` запускает dev сервер, то `build` делает билд. Если перейдете по ссылке которую я привел, там тоже все написано.

Comment: @Simon спасибо за уточнение. Наверно мне не стоит ориентироваться на видео 2 летней давности, у меня там другая проблема появилась, с версионностью файлов.

Comment: Попробуй посмотреть данный раздел: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/vite#running-vite